# Couldnt find Osirix Plugin Generator. How to start to develop plugin for osirix?

Tags: objective-c

As per the links at Osirix webpages, the link https://osirix.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/osirix/plugin seems to be destroyed where Osirix Plugin Generator apple script and the tutorial for developing plugin for osirix are present. Please guide how to start for developing a simple plugin for osirix in obejective C. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

They moved the project over to Github.  Here's the plugin generator and samples link:

https://github.com/pixmeo/osirixplugins

Like Nelson Terra said, you can find the generator in the /_help directory.  The other folders are all sample plugins you can check out.  As for a guide, this site helped me when I first started with OsiriX:

http://osirixpluginbasics.wordpress.com/

Also here's a good forum that has a lot of useful snippets:

http://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/osirix-dev/info

Answer (score 1):

You can find some documentation here:
http://osirix.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/osirix/Documentation/Guides/Development/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I just found this project: https://osirixplugins.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/osirixplugins . In this project you can find the /_help directory and inside it the osirix plugin generator, I will try this...good luck for us.

Answer (score 0):

The new plugin template is in the folder called

```
osirixplugins/_help/MyNewPluginTemplate/
```

at the github repository:

```
https://github.com/pixmeo/osirixplugins.git
```

You can use that and customise the code. This works instead of a Generator script...